# GCP ML-engine FailedPreconditionError (code: 2)

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, prediction, google-cloud-ml

I am facing an error with Google Cloud Platform and ml-engine.

I trained a tf.keras.model and I saved it using:

```
tf.contrib.saved_model.save_keras_model(my_model, "gs://my_bucket").
```

I created the model and the version on Cloud ML-engine, but when I run a local prediction:

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=./saved_models/1554973923 --json-instances=./inst.json --verbosity debug
```

I get this strange error:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): 
Error while reading resource variable sequence_decoder/recurrent_kernel_1 from Container: localhost. 
This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. 
Not found: Resource localhost/sequence_decoder/recurrent_kernel_1/N10tensorflow3VarE does not exist.
[[node sequence_decoder/while/ReadVariableOp_17 (defined at /.../google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/ml_sdk/cloud/ml/prediction/frameworks/tf_prediction_lib.py:210) ]]
(Error code: 2)
```

Does anybody know why is it happening?

I am using tensorflow 1.13.1 and python 3.6

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: When you save your model with debug enabled, do you see any "Signatures INCLUDED in export for Predict: ['serving_default']"  This is a similar example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/tf-keras with serving enabled.

Comment: You have to create a reference for the session that is used for loading the models and then set it to be used by keras in each request.Please refer to the following [answer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28287#issuecomment-495005162) which explains in detail on how to create a reference to the session.